How to enable code completion and suggestions in Android Studio for Node.js?
I'm using Android Studio as my integrated development environment (IDE) for a Flutter project that integrates with a Node.js backend. While coding in Android Studio, I've noticed that it doesn't provide code completion or suggestions for Node.js code, unlike Visual Studio Code (VSCode), which offers these features out of the box.
For example, in VSCode, when I type auth. and hit the autocomplete key combination, it shows me a list of available methods and properties from the auth object:

However, in Android Studio, when I try the same action, it doesn't display any suggestions or code completion hints:

This lack of code completion and suggestions makes coding in Node.js within Android Studio a bit more challenging, as I have to manually look up available methods, properties, and their respective parameters.
Can someone please guide me on how to enable code completion and suggestions for Node.js code in Android Studio? This feature would greatly improve my development workflow and productivity.

Unfortunately you have to use and pay for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate to have code completion for Node.js, as you can see in the comparison of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition: https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=idea-ce
In the IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition code completion for Node.js and JavaScript is not supported.
